# Load data based on user inputs

Tags: python, flask

I am working with dynamic data that requires an ID and a year to load, both of which are input by the user. The ID is unique, so two users will very likely be looking at different data. They are passed into a URL that returns a large dictionary. This dictionary is then passed to a bunch of other functions for various analyses and visuals. I was thinking of displaying the data in its own hidden route and have other routes call on it (I am new to flask, so there could be a better/more efficient way of storing and accessing dynamic data like this).

Here is the flask code to display the form and where I try to access the data:

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
        return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/data/<lid>/<ssn>", methods=["GET","POST"])
def data_league():
    if request.method == "POST":
        league_id = request.form["lid"]
        season = request.form["ssn"]
        
        url = 'http://fantasy.espn.com/apis/v3/games/ffl/seasons/' + season + '/segments/0/leagues/' + league_id + '?view=mMatchupScore&view=mTeam&view=mSettings'
        r = requests.get(url,
                         params={'view':'mMatchup'})
        d = r.json()
        
        return d
```

And the HTML code that creates the form:

```
    <form class="row row-cols-lg-auto g-3 align-items-center" action="#" method="post" style="margin- 
     left: 180px;">
      <div class="col-5">
        <label class="visually-hidden" for="league_id">Username</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lid" id="lId" placeholder="League ID">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-5">
        <label class="visually-hidden" for="season">Preference</label>
        <select class="form-select" name="ssn" id="Ssn">
          <option selected>Select a Season</option>
          <option value="1">2020</option>
          <option value="2">2019</option>
          <option value="3">2018</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

When I run the app and input an ID and year, I get a TypeError saying that "data_league() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lid'". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: def data_league(lid, ssn): then remove your lid=request.form["..."] after
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules

Comment: I did that and get the error "TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement". I thought I had to wrap the "d" variable in json.dumps(d) and return that, but it gave me the same error. I also tried rendering the original "index.html" template and adding "d=d" after, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Because `if request.method == "POST":` is false, then nothing is return. Add a return statement if the request is not POST.